# How to notify email subscribers on new posts in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, function, email, notifications

How to notify email subscribers on new posts thru PHP? The subscribers' email is stored outside Wordpress, let say it's stored on another server.

I found several articles, like this.. [Article 1](http://wp-snippets.com/automatically-notify-your-members-on-new-posts/)

but it only send an email to all registered users in Wordpress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, in this case, you may need to use the Wordpress save_post hook which is fired after a post has been saved. You can read more here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post

So, what you could do is something like this in your functions.php file

```
function on_create_send_email( $post_id ) {

    // If this is just a revision, don't send the email.
    if ( wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) )
        return;

    //Handle your users and send the emails
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'on_create_send_email' );
```

How you choose to handle the mass email would be a matter of personal preference. There are plugins that will help out or you could integrate this with something like Mailchimp.

Comment: How can I call the table of subscribers? If the database is outside wordpress (different server) should I define the database connection?

Comment: It's not something that I, myself, have had to do before but this article here: http://bavotasan.com/2011/access-another-database-in-wordpress/ explains the process quite well and you should be quite easily eable to connect to and query the external database using the approach detailed within there

Answer (score 1):

If sending a daily update works for your situation, my suggestion would be to use [MailChimp's RSS-to-Email feature](http://mailchimp.com/features/rss-to-email/). It will only fire (at the same time every day) if there are new posts, and it won't ever include posts that have already been included in a previous email.

The one thing this feature doesn't do, is send immediate updates. In other words: if you want an email to be sent out the second a post is published, you'll need a plugin like [this one](https://wordpress.org/plugins/autochimp/) (a little outdated). Or [this one](https://nl.wordpress.org/plugins/demomentsomtres-mailchimp-immediate-send/). That is, if you're OK using MailChimp for sending out your emails (highly recommened though). I haven't used any of these plugins myself, so I won't be able to comment on their quality / ease of use - but I hope this helps you find your solution.